# how does this Ruby code work? (hash) (Learnrubythehardway)

Tags: ruby, hash

I know i will look like a total noob, but there's something I can't wrap my head around. Let me emphasize that i DID google this thing, but i didn't find what I was looking for.

I'm going through the `learnrubythehardway` course, and for [ex39](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex39.html) this is one of the functions we have defined:

```
def Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
    return key.hash % aDict.length
end
```

The author gives this explanation:

> hash_key
>       This deceptively simple function is the core of how a hash works. What it does is uses the built-in Ruby hash function to convert a
>   string to a number. Ruby uses this function for its own hash data
>   structure, and I'm just reusing it. You should fire up a Ruby console
>   to see how it works. Once I have a number for the key, I then use the
>   `% (modulus)` operator and the `aDict.length` to get a bucket where this
>   key can go. As you should know, the `% (modulus)` operator will divide
>   any number and give me the remainder. I can also use this as a way of
>   limiting giant numbers to a fixed smaller set of other numbers. If you
>   don't get this then use Ruby to explore it

I like this course, but the above paragraph was no help.
Ok, you call the function passing it two arguments (`aDict` is an array) and it returns something.
(My questions are not totally independent of one another.)

1. What and how does it do that? (ok, it returns a bucket index, but how do we "get there"?)
2. What does the `key.hash` do/what is it?
3. How does using the `%` help me get what I need? (What is the use of "modding" the `key.hash` by the `aDict.length`?)
4. "Use Ruby to explore it." - ok, but my question No.2. kinda already suggests that I wouldn't know how to go about doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key.hash` is calling [Object#hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash), which is not to be confused with [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

`Object#hash` converts a string into a number consistently (the same string will always result in the same number, in the same running instance of Ruby).

```
pry(main)> "abc".hash
=> -1672853150
```

So now we have a number, but it's way too large for the number of buckets in our `Dict` structure, which defaults to 256 buckets. So we modulus it to get a number within our bucket range.

```
pry(main)> "abc".hash % 256
=> 98
```

This essentially allows us to translate `Dict["abc"]` into `aDict[98]`.

Comment: I agree with your explanation after reading through that page (you beat me to answering!). What I don't understand is how the author is confident that using a modulus operation like that isn't going to greatly increase the chances of a collision. But I don't want to get the thread too off-track.

Comment: @RobW. Right, this is the introductory example of building a hash table.  Modulo is very much not a good way to do this by itself, but I think this is a pretty common first step into understanding the process.

Comment: @RobW. Yeah, I considered discussing collisions but didn't want to sidetrack the thread either. This is a conceptual implementation for beginners after all.

Comment: I don't remember quite when this changed but the String#hash will only produce a consistent value for a given string for the lifetime of a ruby process (so that it is harder to maliciously cause collisions)

Comment: @FrederickCheung .. Do you happen to have further reading about that available?  Never thought of that potential problem before..

Comment: According to https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/12/28/denial-of-service-attack-was-found-for-rubys-hash-algorithm-cve-2011-4815/ this was changed in a patch release of 1.8.7. The hashing algorithm changed in 1.9 and again when a weakness was found in that hash function ( https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/11/09/ruby19-hashdos-cve-2012-5371/ )

Answer (score 1):

### RE: This example in particular

I'm going to change the order of things in a way that I hope makes more sense:

#2. You can think of a hash as a sort of 'fingerprint' of something.  The `.hash` method will create a (generally) unique output for any given input.

#3. In this case, we know that the hash is a number, so we take the modulo of the generated number by the backing array's length in order to find a (hopefully empty) index that is within our storage's bounds.

#1. That's how.  A hashing algorithm will return the same output for any given input.  The modulo takes this output and turns it into something we can actually use in an array to find something reliably.

#4. Call `hash` on something.  Call it on a string and then modulo it by the length of an array.  Try again on another string.  Do that again, and use your result to assign something to that array.  Do it again to see that the hash and modulo thing will find that value again.

### Further Notes:

By itself, the modulo function is not a good way to pick unique indexes for keys.  This example is the first step, but especially in a small array, there is still a relatively large chance for the hashes of different keys to modulo into the same number.  That's called a collision, and handling those seems to be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks, oobivat.
I don't have the reputation points to upvote your reply yet, but I do appreciate it.

Comment: @metrazol All good.  Points are nice and all, but that's not really why I take time to do this.

Comment: @metrazol .. No problem.  Actual hash table implementations are really cool because they are able to solve the collision problem while keeping data access time very low.  -- As for your edit, I think you're just missing a back quote.